# Is it acceptable to delete my question if I get downvote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-questions

Is it acceptable to delete my own question if I get a downvote? I have been spending time to create questions with proper support documentation. Even though I got a downvote, I wish to delete it to get my reputation back.

But I got a notification which says, if you delete question with answer you will not be able to ask questions in the future.

How can I get rid out from it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the question is at all salvageable, then you should do your best to figure out what you did wrong, and how you can correct it.

If you now understand why the question is problematic, and you don't feel that you can possibly edit the question into an acceptable question, then yes, you should delete it.  Note that if you *do* end up deleting the question you should use this as an opportunity to learn from your mistake, and to be more careful in the future when asking questions (take the opportunity to read through the help center and the numerous other sources of information on how to ask an appropriate question, both to figure out if you can salvage this one, and to ensure that future questions are appropriate).  As the message is telling you, if you continue to ask low quality questions you will end up being banned from asking more questions, although if your future questions are appropriate then this won't be a problem for you.